How do I add bullets points entries in flutter textfield?
I'm trying to add bullets points in textfield of flutter but unable to do that.
I have done R&D regarding the same and found this but this is also not satisfying solution.
here is the full code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const String bullet = '\u2022';

class SampleView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleView({super.key});

  @override
  State<SampleView> createState() => _SampleViewState();
}

class _SampleViewState extends State<SampleView> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  int currentTextLength = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            minLines: 1,
            maxLines: 5,
            controller: controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Type Here..."
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                if (value[0] != bullet) {
                  value = '$bullet $value';
                  controller.text = value;
                  controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                      TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
                }
                if (value[value.length - 1] == '\n' &&
                    value.length > currentTextLength) {
                  controller.text = '$value$bullet ';
                  controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                      TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
                }
                currentTextLength = controller.text.length;
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



output with issue :
see this video
As you can see if I start editing the text in the middle, bullet points is not being added after new line.

After a lots of research I found the solution with the help of my senior. He suggested me to use inputFormatters of TextField() widget.
and magically it worked as I wanted.
Here's the full code :

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';





class SampleView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleView({super.key});

  @override
  State<SampleView> createState() => _SampleViewState();
}

class _SampleViewState extends State<SampleView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            minLines: 1,
            maxLines: 5,
            inputFormatters: [CustomTextEditingFormatter()], //<--using the custom formatter here
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Type Here..."),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


CustomTextEditingFormatter class :

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

const String bullet = '\u2022';

class CustomTextEditingFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    String newText = "";
    if (newValue.text.isNotEmpty) {
      if (newValue.text.length > oldValue.text.length) {
        var taskList = newValue.text.split("\n");
        int cursor = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < taskList.length; index++) {
          String temp = taskList[index];
          if (!temp.contains(bullet)) {
            temp = '$bullet $temp';
            if (index == taskList.length - 1) {
              cursor = cursor + 2;
            } else {
              cursor++;
            }
          }
          newText = "$newText${index == 0 ? "" : "\n"}$temp";
          newValue = TextEditingValue(
              text: newText,
              selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
                  offset: (newValue.selection.end + cursor)));
        }
      }
    }

    return newValue;
  }
}


Output video :  see video
But I think, this is also not best approach.
Well I found a plugin named as flutter_quill which supports many editing features like bullets points, listing, check listing  and text highlighting and many more.
I'm gonna use this.
